# Generate RSA keys using javascript?

Tags: javascript, rsa

Is there a way to generate both private and public keys using javascript?

And I need to those key in a database.

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIICXQIBAAKBgQDlOJu6TyygqxfWT7eLtGDwajtNFOb9I5XRb6khyfD1Yt3YiCgQ
>   WMNW649887VGJiGr/L5i2osbl8C9+WJTeucF+S76xFxdU6jE0NQ+Z+zEdhUTooNR
>   aY5nZiu5PgDB0ED/ZKBUSLKL7eibMxZtMlUDHjm4gwQco1KRMDSmXSMkDwIDAQAB
>   AoGAfY9LpnuWK5Bs50UVep5c93SJdUi82u7yMx4iHFMc/Z2hfenfYEzu+57fI4fv
>   xTQ//5DbzRR/XKb8ulNv6+CHyPF31xk7YOBfkGI8qjLoq06V+FyBfDSwL8KbLyeH
>   m7KUZnLNQbk8yGLzB3iYKkRHlmUanQGaNMIJziWOkN+N9dECQQD0ONYRNZeuM8zd
>   8XJTSdcIX4a3gy3GGCJxOzv16XHxD03GW6UNLmfPwenKu+cdrQeaqEixrCejXdAF
>   z/7+BSMpAkEA8EaSOeP5Xr3ZrbiKzi6TGMwHMvC7HdJxaBJbVRfApFrE0/mPwmP5
>   rN7QwjrMY+0+AbXcm8mRQyQ1+IGEembsdwJBAN6az8Rv7QnD/YBvi52POIlRSSIM
>   V7SwWvSK4WSMnGb1ZBbhgdg57DXaspcwHsFV7hByQ5BvMtIduHcT14ECfcECQATe
>   aTgjFnqE/lQ22Rk0eGaYO80cc643BXVGafNfd9fcvwBMnk0iGX0XRsOozVt5Azil
>   psLBYuApa66NcVHJpCECQQDTjI2AQhFc1yRnCU/YgDnSpJVm1nASoRUnU8Jfm3Oz
>   uku7JUXcVpt08DFSceCEX9unCuMcT72rAQlLpdZir876
>   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>
> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDlOJu6TyygqxfWT7eLtGDwajtN
>   FOb9I5XRb6khyfD1Yt3YiCgQWMNW649887VGJiGr/L5i2osbl8C9+WJTeucF+S76
>   xFxdU6jE0NQ+Z+zEdhUTooNRaY5nZiu5PgDB0ED/ZKBUSLKL7eibMxZtMlUDHjm4
>   gwQco1KRMDSmXSMkDwIDAQAB
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Check out http://wwwtyro.github.io/cryptico/

If you are saving the keys to a database anyway it could be worth your while looking at doing this server side using something like nodejs

Have a look here https://github.com/juliangruber/keypair that library hasn't been updated in some time so it may be worth a search.

Comment: It's on the cliente side. Is there a way to get the private key using cryptico to store it in a database?

Comment: All database storage has to be done server side. If you generate something client side it has to be passed to the server and the web server code would then pass it to the database for storage.

Have a google of these:
PHP
NodeJS

MongoDB
MariaDB

If you have never written server side code there are plenty of youtube tutorials out there, "Derek Banas" and "The New Boston" are a couple.

Comment: Do not use cryptico for any purpose.  According to [this issue](https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico/issues/20) that's been open since 2016, cryptico apparently replaces the global random number generator for Javascript with a deterministic, seedable PRNG.  That's a major security issue.  cryptico is also a dead project as it was archived on GitHub since August 2022.

Answer (score 7):

this question is 4 years old but I found it well before this answer below,
I don't think the Web Crypto API existed at the time.
it can do RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5, RSA-PSS, RSA-OAEP, ECDSA, or ECDH. key pairs on client side
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CryptoKeyPair

```
SubtleCrypto.generateKey()
SubtleCrypto.deriveKey();
```

Comment: Relevant MDN page with code examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey

Comment: Works great, when the page is using SSL. otherwise, cryptico.js is your solution. Very much recommend SSL, though..